# Do La Paz' cable cars have any UV protection on their windows, and if so, what's the protection?

Tags: public-transport, health, bolivia, la-paz

Do [La Paz' cable cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi_Telef%C3%A9rico) have any UV protection on their windows, and if so, what's the protection?

---

Answering some comments:

- @GiacomoCatenazzi: Travel can be easily over 30 minutes, and well over one hour if touring the city via cable cars. UV index in La Paz is often extreme https://www.weatheronline.co.uk/Bolivia/LaPaz/UVindex.htm
- @JonCuster: From https://thoughtco.com/does-glass-block-uv-light-608316:

  > Glass that is transparent to visible light absorbs nearly all UVB. About 75% of UVA passes through ordinary glass. UVA leads to skin damage and genetic mutations that can lead to cancer. Glass does not protect you from skin damage from the sun.

Comment: Can I ask the reason of your question? Travel are short, and cabins travel near soil, so with "frequent" stops (so use UV protection you use waling in the city). As i remember the cabins are new, with original windows (brownish), and not scratches [so good also for photography]

Comment: Either glass or plastic will do at least OK on UV protection. If doing anything else other than riding around in them, you would need your own protection (sun screen, shirt, sun glasses), so counting on the windows to protect you is asking a bit much.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi travel can be easily over 30 minutes, and well over one hour if touring the city via cable cars. UV index in la Paz is often extreme https://www.weatheronline.co.uk/Bolivia/LaPaz/UVindex.htm

Comment: @JonCuster "Glass that is transparent to visible light absorbs nearly all UVB. ... About 75% of UVA passes through ordinary glass. UVA leads to skin damage and genetic mutations that can lead to cancer. Glass does not protect you from skin damage from the sun" source: https://www.thoughtco.com/does-glass-block-uv-light-608316

Comment: From https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19614895 - "Laminated glass totally blocked UVA radiation, while smooth ordinary glass transmitted the highest dose (74.3%)" - Since the glass is going to be some kind of safety glass (for, well, safety to prevent it from shattering in an accident), it is laminated.

Comment: Ok. I would just use the protection you will use in the city.The cars are at height of the buildings (and so it makes it nice), and they have a roof, so no UV from above, and whey sun is on the side, there is less UV. Try to avoid rush hours, where you cannot choose your seat (not on sunny side, but this is also for IR [sun heat]). My problem with La Paz is not UV, but lack of oxygen [and I went last winter, so with nose not at 100%]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi well in the city I use a combination of anti-UV umbrella hat and scarf so it'd prefer not to use them in the cable car :) as mentioned in https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/151399/1810 we have to be really careful about reflecting UV, so roof isn't enough even if it's noon.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks very much this is great information and I wasn't aware of that! I now have to improve my skills to recognize laminated from non-laminated glass. I've read "Laminated glass has a visible interlayer. It also sounds different from annealed or tempered glass when knocked on" but other tips to recognize laminated glass are welcome!

Comment: Anything marked as safety glass is laminated - it has a layer of plastic sandwiched between two glass sheets. The purpose is to hold the glass together. Almost any glass on a moving vehicle will have safety glass since spraying glass shards onto passengers in an accident is not a good effect. Although that is based on US law, so perhaps not applicable to Lima. Look for a little safety symbol in some corner of the glass.

Comment: @JonCuster Tempered glass may also be marketed as safety glass. Please see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_glass). One trivial example is the side windows on your car - they're tempered glass, whilst the wind screen is laminated. The reason laminated glass does not transmit UVA is the plastic component between the two panes of glass.